# Need reference document or code for jdbc Kafka connect configuration setup for distributed mode as docker container

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to design and configure Kafka jdbc connect project where source and sink both are postgres db, and I am using apache Kafka 2.8.

I have prepared POC for standalone mode, but I need to design it for distributed mode and data volume would be several million records.

Can you share any reference to setup for distributed mode and also parameters tuning and best practices?

I have gone through several documents but not getting precise document only for apache Kafka with jdbc connector.

Also please let me know how can I make this solution dockerized?

Thanks,

Suvendu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reference to setup for distributed mode

This is in the Kafka documentation. Run `connect-distributed.sh` along with its config file.

> parameters tuning and best practices?

The config has reasonable defaults, but you're welcome to inspect the file for any changes. Only other thing would be heap settings, but 2G is the default Xmx, and can be set with `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` env var

This starts an HTTP server, and you POST JSON to it that has the same key values as the standalone jdbc worker file

> precise document only for apache Kafka with jdbc connector

There's the official configuration page and handful of blogs (by Confluent) about it

> how can I make this solution dockerized?

The Confluent Docker images would be best for this, though you may have to `confluent-hub install` the JDBC connector into an image of your own

I'd recommend Debezium as the source, though

Comment: Thanks @onecricketeer, Can you tell me how should I attach/configure sink "reporter" to report in elastic? Will it be another connector worker?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-elasticsearch-connector-tutorial/... or https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/

Comment: Thanks @onecricketeer for reply, actually I want to have "reporter.result.topic.name" configured after sink operation and I then want to save the data from topic of  "reporter.result.topic.name" to Elastic. I have made kafka-connect running using docker-compose. So I need tutorials and concept if I can configure "reporter" part.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `reporter.result.topic.name` is not a Kafka Connect property name and there's no concept/term named "reporter". Outside of that, asking for tutorials is off topic - [help], but the above links show you how to sink any topic to Elastic

Comment: Actually I was referring "Connect reporter" from this link but still did not get how to configure it at my kafka-connect docker sink operation. "https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#userguide-connect-reporter". I need to configure for both success and failure operations.

Comment: I see. This must be a new feature that I'm not familiar with, but you can add those properties into any sink connector, supposedly, but you need a second sink connector with no reporter if you want to sink the reporter topic itself into Elastic... That doesn't change anything about how to use or configure the Elastic sink on its own